# Function doesn't work, but it must work

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void Main_OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = Classes.Global.X.ToString();
    Classes.Global.PositionChanged(this);
}
```

`PositionChanged` writes to X new x-position of window. It works, but as soon as I delete `label1` it stops working. No errors.

Comment: Have you thought perhaps that, when you delete label1, the first line of that function will cause a problem. Why you get no error, I don't know, unless there's another label1 floating around somewhere.

Comment: A little more context would be helpful.

Comment: The title is absolutely, completely, and totally *useless*.

Comment: You might say the title doesn't work, but it must work

Comment: Can you share the code of the `PositionChanged` method?

Comment: public static void PositionChanged(Window anyWindow)
        {
            X = anyWindow.Left;
            Y = anyWindow.Top;
        }

I delete label1 and the first line*

Answer (score 1):

My guess,  Classes.Global.X  does something ( perhaps creates a singleton? ) and PositionChanged checks to see if something is null  that x would of created and hence does nothing?

try  var x = Classes.Global.X   instead of the label.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete label1, then trying to set anything to label1 will probably through an exception which is ignored, may be object disposed exception or null reference exception would cause it, try wrapping everything in try catch and log the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab here and suggest not deleting label1, but simply setting label1's visible property to false.

At least that way you can maintain the method and not break the app.

Comment: "Maintain the method"? It's two lines. Better to solve the mystery now before the label1 issue nests itself deep.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just assumed the guy didn't want to adjust the method.  Keith has a much better guess to the problem anyways.